# Web.Config Assembly/Reference Issue

Tags: asp.net, web-config

Today I had to re-create my web.config file, and have lost my previous code.
I have my database connection and roles working fine, however, my assemblies never seem to work... In my back-end code, I always get the error

> The type or namespace name 'Insert Here' does not extist in the namespace 'Insert Here' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My current config file's assembly section has been created by Visual Web Developer by using the Add Reference option:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation>
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="mscorlib"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="*" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
---rest of code here---
```

Just incase it means anything, the tutorials I followed when making my database Membership friendly directed my to the aspnet_regsql.exe in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 directory, but the versions in my web.config are 4.0.0.0. Could this have something to do with it? Should I use the exe found in the v4.0.30319 folder?

If someone could please help me try to get this fixed... I really can't make any progress on my site anymore as all non-database stuff is done...

Answer (score 1):

I figured there was something wrong with my web.config files, so I just made a new website, copied everything over from the original folder and it works. 
I know it may not have been the best solution, but it took maybe 10 minutess, far less than the time I've already wasted.